# dead lock when updating

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

```
 Update Operation.TrTable
 Set    RecordId = RecordTABLE.newRecordId
 From  Operation.TrTable tr
    Inner Join (
        SELECT r.Id AS newRecordId, r.KeyM AS MappingKey
        From  Operation.Record r
        WHERE r.KeyM > 0
      ) RecordTABLE
      ON RecordTABLE.MappingKey = tr.KeyM
 WHERE tr.KeyM > 0  



UPDATE Operation.Record SET KeyM = 0 
WHERE KeyM > 0 

UPDATE Operation.TrTable SET KeyM = 0
WHERE KeyM > 0
```

The error is:

> Transaction (Process ID 93) was deadlocked on lock | communication
>   buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the
>   deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Comment: Do you have the deadlock graph (XML) to post?

Comment: sorry it was on the remote server i dont have deadlock graph yet but it is very strange to have this deadlock :(

Comment: the error is : Transaction (Process ID 93) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Comment: Is it R2 or 'plain' 2008?

Comment: This link will help you find the deadlock graph.  In it you will be able to see both sides of the deadlock.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/deadlock/65658/

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: I've modified the lock suggestion to `XLOCK`, per the comments below.]

Without really understanding any of the details about your particular situation (you haven't shared any!), I'd guess you are running the above code in multiple sessions concurrently.  You may be able to prevent deadlocks by modifying your code as such:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE Operation.TrTable
    SET    RecordId = RecordTABLE.newRecordId
    FROM  Operation.TrTable tr WITH (XLOCK)
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT r.Id AS newRecordId, r.KeyM AS MappingKey
            FROM  Operation.Record r WITH (XLOCK)
            WHERE r.KeyM > 0
        ) RecordTABLE ON RecordTABLE.MappingKey = tr.KeyM
    WHERE tr.KeyM > 0; 

    UPDATE Operation.Record SET KeyM = 0 
    WHERE KeyM > 0;

    UPDATE Operation.TrTable SET KeyM = 0
    WHERE KeyM > 0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    /*
        handle any errors here - perhaps send an email
        or raise a custom error messsage
    */
END CATCH
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Note I've added `WITH (XLOCK)` to your `FROM` clauses, since the same records you are `SELECTing` will later be updated.  `WITH (XLOCK)` will place an exclusive lock on the selected records preventing them from being read by other sessions until the current transaction completes.  As Jon Seigel said in his comment below, we really need more information about your exact issue to make an accurate diagnosis.

Comment: Update locks don't prevent concurrent reads. In fact, allowing concurrent reads is the entire reason update locks exist. Also, using the `UPDLOCK` hint specifies to take real update (U) locks, not intent-update (IU) locks (I'm not sure if you actually meant that or not). The lone `UPDLOCK` hint on `Operation.TrTable` is default behaviour as it's an `UPDATE` statement for that table. In any event, I think we need to see a deadlock graph before drawing any conclusions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, Jon.  If I were to replace the UPDLOCK with XLOCK, that would have the desired effect, would it not?

Comment: Yep, that would do it. Then, assuming the rows in the query are accessed in the same order from execution to execution (I'm not sure if this is a good assumption or not), that should prevent deadlocks from happening.

Comment: ...assuming the problem is what you identified as the problem. (We don't know.)